# Use Microsoft Graph API List channel messages without admin role users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are having a Tenant that has Global Tenant Admin and number of Users who is not having any Admin roles.
In Microsoft Graph explorer we can able to get the list of messages(GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages)  using Admin account.

But when we tried using one of the user account it says the user is not having permission to perform this action. We tried to modify the Permissions but 'ChannelMessage.Read.All' is not there and if the available 'Group.ReadWrite.All' is selected then it shows

*Need admin approval
Graph explorer
Graph explorer needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.
Have an admin account? Sign in with that account*

Is that possible to use the List channel messages API using normal user credentials ? 
If so how to enable that and will that also work for accessing programmatically using Node JS REST API calls?

@ Trinetra-MSFT , @Victor Marcus

Here is the Modify Permission screenshot and it is not having ChannelMessage.Read.All. Am I missing something ? It is a tenant global admin account.

[Modify Permission from Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wPfW.jpg)

Comment: You can use normal credentials but those permission should be granted by admin

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT. Is Group.ReadWrite.All enough ?

Comment: ChannelMessage.Read.All, Group.Read.All,Group.ReadWrite.All These permission should be there to call. You can see the channel message permissions in delegated or application mode

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Can you look on the screenshot of modify permission from MS Graph explorer shared in post. It is not having ChannelMessage.Read.All. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Graph Explorer doesn't show all the permissions you need to check it in [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com)

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT That means Admin needs to delegate the permission to the users through azure portal. Then only Users can use the delegated permission. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to read channel messages using normal user credentials. In this case, you will only get the messages of the channels the user is part of. The permissions you need are **ChannelMessage.Read.All** and **Group.ReadWrite.All**. You will find these permissions in Microsoft Graph Application permissions. These permissions need to be granted by a global admin. Here, I have attached the image of the channel permission.

[image]

Comment: Thank you . In the permission page I have Group.ReadWrite.All only. I could not see ChannelMessage.Read.All.

Comment: Can you share screenshot for the search of channelmessage

Comment: Can you look on the screenshot of modify permission from MS Graph explorer shared in post. It is not having ChannelMessage.Read.All. Am I missing something ?

Comment: In explorer, you don't need channelMessage.Read.All,  Can you share what permissions are consented to you. The consented permissions have a green check near them.